# Connect to mysql in a Docker container from another Docker container in a MacOS host

Tags: mysql, macos, docker

I have been trying to set up several Docker containers for different mysql databases in my MacOS host system. 
So, I have 2 different mysql databases in containers built from the mysql/mysql-server:5.7 image.

```
docker run --name=db-1 -d -p 1200:3306 mysql/mysql-server:5.7
docker run --name=db-2 -d -p 1201:3306 mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

Since they are binded to 0.0.0.0:120x, I am able to access the mysql cli using

```
mysql -uroot -p -h 0.0.0.0 -P 120x (WORKS)
```

However, I really wanted to try and access the databases using the IP of the container which I found using

```
docker inspect db-1 | grep IPAddress
```

I found that the IP of the container is 172.17.0.8
So logically

```
mysql -uroot -p -h 172.17.0.8 -P 3306
```

should have worked, but it doesn't. 
I get an error that reads out ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.8' (60)

I was trying to access using the container IP so I could access the databases from other containers by linking them. However this doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are trying to connect to your Mysql from outside the container, I think you are not using the right port. Did you try to connect using `mysql -uroot -p -h 172.17.0.8 -P 120x` ? The port 3306 will only be available from inside the container

Comment: @aveuiller That doesn't sound too logical, if 172.17.0.8 is the IP of the container, it makes sense to use the internal port that it exposes, doesn't it? Nevertheless, tried it and no luck.

Comment: The port 3306 is the port exposed internally, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports). So as far as I can see from your docker run, the container is exposing `3306` internally, and you routed the port to respectively `1200` and `1201` on db-1 and db-2. So from the outside you should only be able to connect through the ports `1200` and `1201`. Could you try to see if the any port is available on your container from the outside using `telnet 172.17.0.8 $port` (trying both 1200 and 3306)?

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses don't work on OS X; looking them up is usually a mistake.  Your first form (using the 127.0.0.1 "localhost" address, not the 0.0.0.0 "everywhere" address) using the published port is correct.

Comment: @david maze, thanks for the clarification. Can you also help me with how can I then connect the to the mysql container from a different application container? Since 127.0.0.1 is the localhost of the host ...